# Call Object from another method - JAVA

Tags: java, object

I have met the foolish case :(, I have tried call Object from another method but always return null (I have added Getter...).

Can someone figured out my problem.

Here my code:

```
    private Email email;

    public void loadPage() {  // Call from init page 
                email = emailDAO.findById(40); // I debugged here and had values                
    }

    public String changeResetPassword() { // Call by click button event
                email.getSender(); // Error here - java.lang.NullPointerException
    }   

    public Email getEmail() {
                return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(Email email) {
                this.email = email;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you call `loadPage` and `changeResetPassword` in the correct order and moreover on the same instance ?

Answer (score 1):

Force the field to be assigned in the `getEmail` method accessing it, this will eliminate the [temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/):

```
public Email getEmail() {
    if(email == null){
        this.loadPage();
    }
    return email;
}
```

An alternative would be to move the invocation of `loadPage` to the classes constructor to ensure the email is always loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
I declared same object name and when load page it new object again, that the reason why I always get null return.

Thank you all.